# Redux Form calling MapStateToProps for each Field element after upgrading from v6.8 to v7.4.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I just updated Redux Form for my React project from v6.8 to v7.4.2 and am having issues with mapStateToProps being called for each Field element that I have on the form.

All my forms were working fine under v6.8, but the issue came up when I upgraded. The form eventually renders, but if I have a large form with various logic to come up with initial values, they would take a long time to render.

I don't see any guides on migrating from v6 to v7, and I cannot seem to find similar issues here. What do I need to do to solve this problem?

The render function on the form component runs only once and componentDidUpdate only fires once as well when I load the component.

Here is how I have set Redux Form in the component in simplified form:

```
function getInitialValues() {
  return { field1: 'value for field 1' };
  // this function can be quite long so if called many times, that would be very time consuming.
}

DocumentComponent = reduxForm({
  form: 'documentForm',
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(DocumentComponent);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    initialValues = getInitialValues();

    console.log('mapStateToProps called');
    // logs 2 times when there is 1 Field, 11 times when there are 10 Fields and there would be 101 times if there are 100 Fields.

    return {
      initialValues
    };
  } 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DocumentComponent);
```

Comment: As an update, I am going forward with the assumption that the calling mapStateToProps for each Field is a new feature in v7, so I have adapted my code to get an populated object via an action creator called in componentDidMount. If anyone knows otherwise, please let me know.